# rails + activerecord: how create a hash from table with particular field's value as key

Tags: activerecord, hash

Given a table ZipCodeInfos with fields zipcode, state, city (all strings), where zipcode is unique:

```
zipcode,city,state
"10000", "Fooville", "AA"
"10001", "Smallville", "AA"
"10002", "Whoville", "BB"
```

What is the fastest way to generate a hash object of the entire table where the zipcode is a key like this:

```
{ "10000" => {:city => "Fooville", :state => "AA" },
"10001" => {:city => "Smallville", :state => "AA" },
"10002" => {:city => "Whoville", :state => "BB" } }
```

I know for a given record I can use .attributes to generate a hash with key,value pairs of field-names, field-values, for example `Zipcode.first.attributes` gives me

```
{"id" => 1, "zipcode" => "10000", "city" => "Fooville", "state => "AA" }
```

But, short of brute force iterating over each record (via .map), I cannot quite figure out how to create the desired hash with the zipcode as the key for each node of the hash.

This is the best I could come up with, and I suspect there is some nifty Ruby goodness that is faster?

```
zip_info_hash = {}
ZipCodeInfo.all.map{|x| zip_info_hash[x.zip] = 
                       {'state' => x.state, 'city' => x.city }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try:

```
ZipCodeInfos.all.group_by &:zipcode
```

will get you a hash of zip code to array of ZipCodeInfos activerecords.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inject method.
Here is what I generally use.

```
def visitors_name_email
  visitors.inject({}) do |result, visitor|
    result.merge(visitor.name => visitor.email)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to avoid `map` here. I'd make only some minor changes to your code:

```
zip_info=Hash[*ZipCodeInfo.all
                          .map{|x| [x.zip, {:city => x.city, :state => x.state}]}
                          .flatten]
```